# Trouble Finding a Position Function Given a Dot Product & Initial Value

Tags: vectors, cross-product, initial-value-problems

[image: This is the given problem"]

I tried taking the dot product of r(0) and r'(0) and setting that equal to e^0 = 1 and found that <1,0,0> DOT < a,b,c > = 1  therefore a = 1. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is in noticing that
$$ \vec r\cdot \frac{d \vec r}{dt} = \frac12 \frac{d}{dt}\big(|\vec r|^2\big )$$

Can you finish?

Comment: Ah okay. So you just get Answer choice C? How did you figure out this identity that you defined? Where did you get this from?

Comment: yes the answer is C, and the identity follows from expressing the rhs as a sum of squares and computing the derivatives. I got it from experience with problems, I suppose

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Cheers, bud!